# auto populate the primary contact field with the logged in user

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

there's a field in a form which is a lookup to the contact entity. Also,there's the OOB owner field in crm which is a lookup of system user type. The requirement is to write a javascript which will auto populate the primary contact field with the logged in user i.e with the name of the logged in user same as owner field in crm.

Answer (score 1):

Won't work, contact and system user are different entity types. You can't put a system user in a contact lookup (or vice versa).

You could try which is probably the closest you can get:

1. Create a new lookup on system to contact.
2. Create a workflow which creates a contact for each system user.
3. Set that system user > contact field in the contact lookup - using workflow is easiest.

Or, hide the default contact lookup from your entity and add a system user lookup.